# Data in hashmap does not save after closing app

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm currently creating an app in android studio where I store user input into a hashmap and show it into a listview, but when I close the app and open it back up, the data is gone and it shows an empty listview.

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: save that hash map in sharedpreference. And when you open app again get from that sharedpreference and set in your listview

Comment: Hashmaps are not meant to persist between app sessions. Use shared preferences in android to save them https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences

Comment: A HashMap is an in memory data structure.  It doesn't stay resident in memory once the last reference to it is gone.  If you want to keep it around, write it to disk in some way.  Depending on the type and ways you use the data, that may mean a file, shared preferences, or a database.

Comment: you have to store this into local storage like ROOM Data base, Realm,SharedPreference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have a hashMap `val mp = HashMap<Int, String>()`. Then you need to save the contents of this hashmap when your app closes, and restore data on app open. You can store the map inside `sharedPreference` or `preferenceDataStore`. I'll show you the sharedPreference way:

```kotlin
private val mp: HashMap<Int, String> = HashMap()
    private val preferenceName = "HASHMAP_PREFS"
    private val HASHMAP_KEY = "HASHMAP_KEY"
    private lateinit var sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences

    private fun initPref() {
        if(!this::sharedPreferences.isInitialized) {
            this.sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(preferenceName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        }
    }

    private fun saveHashMap() {
        initPref()
        val editor = this.sharedPreferences.edit()
        val hashMapValue = Gson().toJson(mp)
        editor.putString(HASHMAP_KEY, hashMapValue)
        editor.apply()
    }

    private fun restoreHashMap() {
        initPref()
        val hashMapAsStringValue = this.sharedPreferences.getString(HASHMAP_KEY, null)
        if(hashMapAsStringValue!=null) {
            val hashMapType: Type = object : TypeToken<HashMap<Int, String>>() {}.type
            val tempHashMap: HashMap<Int, String> = Gson().fromJson(hashMapAsStringValue, hashMapType)
            this.mp.putAll(tempHashMap) // the hashMap is restored
        }
        Log.e("TAG", "hashMap = ${mp.toString()}")
    }
```

Here, the function names are self explainatory. Simply save data when app closes:

```kotlin
    override fun onDestroy() {
        saveHashMap()
        super.onDestroy()
    }
```

And restore data on app open:

```kotlin
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)
     
        restoreHashMap()
        val key = System.currentTimeMillis().toInt() % 100
        val value = "${key*2}"
        mp.put(key, value)
        // todo: logic, other codes...
    }
```

**Notice** that in this example, I used HashMap<Int, String>. If you use map of other type, you should change the codes accordingly.

### Edit

This is the java code can look like:

```java
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class DemoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private HashMap<Integer, String> mp = new HashMap<>();
    private String preferenceName = "HASHMAP_PREFS";
    private String HASHMAP_KEY = "HASHMAP_KEY";

    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = null;

    private void initPreference() {
        if(sharedPreferences == null) {
            sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(preferenceName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        }
    }

    private void saveHashMap() {
        initPreference();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String hashMapValue = gson.toJson(mp);
        editor.putString(HASHMAP_KEY, hashMapValue);
        editor.apply();
    }

    private void restoreHashMap() {
        initPreference();

        String hashMapValue = sharedPreferences.getString(HASHMAP_KEY, null);
        if(hashMapValue!=null) {
            Type hashMapType = new TypeToken<HashMap<Integer, String>>(){}.getType();
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            HashMap<Integer, String> restoredHashMap = gson.fromJson(hashMapValue, hashMapType);
            mp.putAll(restoredHashMap);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
        restoreHashMap();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        saveHashMap();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: How would I write this is java? What would I replace with 'val' and with 'fun'?

Comment: I have updated my answer with a java example. Please check it.

Comment: Thank you sm for the code. However, my app does not run as I want it to :(